# Errors resolving NuGet Packages after TFS Download

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm having a strange problem where all of NuGet packages aren't resolving after a full download of the solution from Team Foundation Server in VS2015 Pro.

[image: Errors]

[image: Errors]

The solution was working perfectly before + trying to install packages again VS reckons it already exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to firstly get latest on the project and if that doesnt work reinstall the projects packages using the package manager on the project.

```
Uninstall-Package SimpleCrypto 
Install-Package SimpleCrypto 

Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Owin
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin

Uninstall-Package Owin
Install-Package Owin

Uninstall-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleCrypto/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework