# TFS download having issues with nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm having a similar issue as the following question with Owin: [Errors resolving NuGet Packages after TFS Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098647/errors-resolving-nuget-packages-after-tfs-download).

The errors I have shown after downloading from TFS are: 
The type or namespace name 'Cors' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Owin
The type or namespace name 'HttpListener' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Owin.Host'
...

They do show up in nuget as installed but I've got the exclamation next to the reference in the project.

I already did removed and re-added the packages and it resolves the issue on that computer but I check it in and download it again to a different computer and the issue is still present.  I need the download to work from every computer because of using TFS as a builder.  I see the similar errors showing up there when I initiate a build.

I've tried this on VS2013 and VS2015, VS2013 only has a handful of errors where VS2015 gives me over 1200+ errors and I think there are other issues with the newest nuget and package migration...  So for now, I'm going to concentrate on vs2013.

Comment: Don't put NuGet packages in source control.

Comment: I dont have any nuget packages in source control...